# ASP.NET sending an email to a gmail acc. 2 separate emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, webforms, smtp

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage {
    From = new MailAddress("sender@live.com"),
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Subject = topicLists.SelectedItem.Value,
    Body = txtMsg.Text
};

// Configuring the SMTP Client
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient() {
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("to@gmail.com", "to-pass"),
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
};

// Recipient Address
mail.To.Add("to@gmail.com");

smtp.Send(mail);
```

I expect the result should be something like

---

From: sender@live.com

To: to@gmail.com

---

But what I got is that the sender is **emailing themselves**

From: sender@live.com

To: sender@gmail.com

I don't get why it's not using the other email

Comment: The scenario makes no sense? You want to fake an email from "sender@live.com" in "to@gmail.com"'s inbox?

Comment: May be this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail?rq=1

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder The scenario is something [like this](https://imgur.com/a/CWL09XF). You have an organization contact page, where the user input their email, subject and message (inquiry). So it's from the user's email (sender) to the organization's email (to-receiver)

Comment: Thanks for that @Sarker, but unfortunately this isn't what I need. The credential part is from the sender, which is the user in my case. Asking the user to ask for their email password is definitely wrong

Comment: @AfiqRosli how about https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/insert ? I think Gmail is very strict about the "From" when using SMTP.